# No output to 2nd monitor

Tags: linux, manjaro

I'm using the `video-intel` driver on Manjaro Linux and my 2nd monitor is black-screening; when I connect it it just says "entering power saver mode". I've used the same laptop with Linux Mint 17.3 and I was able attach multiple monitors without issue, so I assume the issue has to do with Manjaro's Intel drivers (I did run into some issues with `mhwd` when I installed Manjaro).

I've tried using `arandr` to configure both monitors. The second monitor shows up but when I try to apply or save the configuration I get:

`XRandR failed: XRandR returned error code 1: xrandr: cannot find mode None`

The second monitor appears to show up as connected when I test with `xrandr -q`. Here is the output below (**HDMI1**):

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 170mm
   1920x1080     60.00 +  40.00  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1200     59.95 +
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x576i      50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x480i      60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  1920x1080 (0x49) 138.659MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  66.66KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1111           clock  60.00Hz
```

Comment: I am having the exact same problem since about a year or so when I got a new ThinkPad T460s and installed Kubuntu 16.04. The external monitor is an LG. I have been trying a lot, but to no avail. For a couple of weeks the monitor started working again just fine, but now it's back to what it was before. I'd be very glad to get help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was solved when Kernel 4.10 was installed through [LTS Enablement Stacks](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack), see also here:

https://askubuntu.com/q/938368/275762.

But after that, the problem reappeared. Due to a different problem I had, I installed Kernel 4.15 using the mainline builds. See:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds?action=show&redirect=KernelMainlineBuilds

That, again, made my external monitor work.

Comment: And now, without any apparent reason, the problem is back with Kernel 4.15. No idea what's happening here..

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem after watching this video on YouTube
https://youtu.be/jD8Wu33fOec

Here's the specific command I used:
`xrandr --output HDMI1 --auto --output HDMI1 --auto --right-of eDP1`
The `HDMI1` and `eDPI` business is specific to your system, use `xrandr -q` to verify your display outputs for your system.